# Php DB wrapper where statement

Tags: php, where-clause

I got this in php Pdo:

```
$db = DBWrapper::getInstance();

$table = "table";
$columns   = array("id", "firstname", "lastname");
$whereRand = array('categorie_bit = :idRand');
$values    = array('idRand' => 00);
$orderBy   = array('RAND()');

$result_set  = $db->select($table,$columns,Null, Null, $orderBy, 1);

foreach($result_set as $result) {}
```

This works, but I am trying to achieve a where statement inside the select I tried this but it did not work:

```
$result_set  = $db->select($table,$columns,$whereRand, Null, $orderBy, 1);
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I believe that `select` method produces, with your parameters, something like `SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM table WHERE categorie_bit = 00 ORDER BY RAND()`. I don't know what `1` stands for... but anyway, that is the problem here?

Comment: I would suggest to review select method defined inside - DBWrapper Class..

Comment: That's not PDO what you are using.

Comment: You aren't passing `$values` anywhere for `select` to know what it should bind to `:idRand`

Comment: You should tag the framework you are using.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider could be, but running inside some framework method

Comment: Put the `select()` code and tell us what means didn't wok.

Comment: @AlanMachado of course it COULD be, but the wrapper COULD also just use `mysql_*` functions *shudder*

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yeah you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, was a pitty mistake....

changed this:

```
$result_set  = $db->select($table,$columns,Null, Null, $orderBy, 1);
```

to this:

```
$result_set  = $db->select($table, $columns, $whereRand, $valuesRand, $orderBy, 1);
```

I forgot to add value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, nowhere it is PDO. But some sort of homebrewed query builder, *of very low quality.*

Instead of using it, better use vanilla PDO:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM table WHERE categorie_bit = :idRand ORDER BY RAND()";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('idRand' => 00));
foreach($stmt as $result) {}
```

Look - it will take you less code to write yet it will let you to use any SQL statement you wish. Not to mention readability of plain SQL, where you can tell what does your query do just at glance. While looking at your function call all you can tell is WTFs. Remember - programs aren't only intended to be written. Sometimes they have to be read. SQL is readable. Good query builder is readable. Just a bunch of variables is not.

Comment: What is `PDOWrapper`?

Comment: Thanks I will remeber, just a question what is "vanilla" e.g. what does that mean?