# Php Sql Pdo update all users

Tags: php, sql

I got this:
(I am getting the current calender week and the starting day of the week and the ending day of the week)

```
# DB
$db = DBWrapper::getInstance();

$table = "staff";
$columns    = array("id", "firstname", "lastname","categorie_bit","calender_week");
$whereDish  = array('categorie_bit = :idDish');
$valuesDish = array('idDish' => 10);
$set = array(
            'calender_week' => $newdate,
            'start_week' => $startWeek,
            'end_week' => $endWeek,
            );
$whereWeek = array('id = :id');
echo '<br>'.$db->update($table, $set, $whereWeek, $valuesWeek).'<br>';
```

how can I make the where statement for the whole ids in the database.
It currently updates one row.

I could write something like this:

```
$valuesWeek_1 = array('id' => 1);
$valuesWeek_2 = array('id' => 2);
$valuesWeek_3 = array('id' => 3);
$valuesWeek_4 = array('id' => 4);
$valuesWeek_5 = array('id' => 5);
$valuesWeek_6 = array('id' => 6);
$valuesWeek_7 = array('id' => 7);
$valuesWeek_8 = array('id' => 8);
$valuesWeek_9 = array('id' => 9);
```

But that is not a good solution

Comment: What does that `update` method? Don't answer "it updates"

Comment: how do you get the id's - please show more information.

Comment: Well it updates the database with the values given, I will edit quick for better understanding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php DB wrapper where statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761821/php-db-wrapper-where-statement)

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like:

```
$whereDish  = array('categorie_bit IN :idsDish');
$valuesDish = array('idsDish' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
```